# kvm tcp vnc connection

Tags: kvm-virtualization, libvirt

Do someone have correct tcp vnc configuration for kvm? I have tried various ways correcting lines in libvirt.conf, qemu.conf, but they do not help (changing listen address, changing flags, changing ports). Vnc always reject to listen on tcp connection. Now I simply remember that initially I should have changed listen_addr for vnc, set listen_tcp = 1, listen_tls = 0.

Comment: What are you trying to do, precisely?

Answer (score 0):

The listen_addr, listen_tcp and listen_tls options you mention here are in libvirtd.conf and affect the *libvirtd* daemon, not QEMU.

By default VNC servers will listen on 127.0.0.1, but this can be changed in qemu.conf, with the 'vnc_listen' parameter.